# Asp.Net ScriptManager causing issues with jQuery Widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I've been using ScriptManager and the jQuery slider widget together on sites for years, but I recently came up against an issue which stopped the widget from working. I managed to resolve the problem, but it was more out of luck than expertise. I'm hoping that someone can provide reasoning behind the issue and that the fix might prove useful to others with the same issue.

I use a script aggregator which combines my scripts together - here is what it contains - all code snippets have been paired down for brevity:

```
vendor/Modernizr.min.js
vendor/jQuery.3.0.0.min.js
vendor/jQuery-UI.1.12.1.min.js
vendor/jQuery-UI.TouchPunch.min.js
propriertary/LoanSelector.js
DefaultInit.js
```

Here is the contents of DefaultInit.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    loanSelector.init();
});
```

Here are the bare bones of LoanSelector.js

```
var loanSelector = function () {

    var pub = {}, $ctl = $("#loan-selector"),
        $sliderAmount = $ctl.find(".slider-amount:first"),
        $widgetAmount = $sliderAmount.find(".widget:first");

    function initControl() {
        initWidgetAmount(100, 2000, 100, $("#hfStartAmount").val());
    }

    function initWidgetAmount(min, max, step, initialVal) {
        $widgetAmount.slider({
        });
    }

    pub.init = function () {
        initControl();
    };

    return pub;
} ();
```

Now this works - but only without ScriptManager on the page.

When script manager is added, the slider widget doesn't load - no errors - nothing.

The cached elements are permanent fixtures on the page - so it's not a case of the elements not existing at a point in time.

Here's the ScriptManager code:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="SM" runat="server"
        EnableCdn="true"
        LoadScriptsBeforeUI="false"
        EnablePageMethods="true">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

If I make changes, I can get the widget to load with the ScriptManager on the page - here's another version of LoanSelector.js that works:

```
var loanSelector = function () {

    var pub = {}, $ctl, $sliderAmount, $widgetAmount;

    function cacheElements() {
        $ctl = $("#loan-selector"),
        $sliderAmount = $ctl.find(".slider-amount:first"),
        $widgetAmount = $sliderAmount.find(".widget:first");
    }

    function initControl() {
        // This is new
        cacheElements();

        initWidgetAmount(100, 2000, 100, $("#hfStartAmount").val());
    }

    function initWidgetAmount(min, max, step, initialVal) {
        $widgetAmount.slider({
        });
    }

    pub.init = function () {
        initControl();
    };

    return pub;
} ();
```

So, can anyone throw some light on why it might not be working and why the fix does work?

Comment: a couple of questions, are there any errors in the console? have you tried putting debugger; into sections of your function to see what is hit? what is the init() function of loanSelector? I see it on the pub object, but you are calling loanSelector.init(), do you just need to call loanSelector()?

Comment: I think possibly ScriptManager must be altering how the scripts are loaded, if the your script loads before the HTML is loaded, then it can't find the element. Easiest way to check this is add "conslole.log( $ctl.length) for each working and non working solutions immediately before calling initWidgetAmount method. If the length is 0, in the non working sample, that indicates the HTML content is not loaded when the method is called.

Comment: @andrewf - I've inspected the page in Chrome and cannot see any obvious errors - pub is the public interface - I call init in document.ready.

Comment: you are nearly there with revealing module pattern. do a check for $(document).ready(function () {
   if(typeof(loanSelector) === "undefined")
    loanSelector.init();
    
}); and if this is true, your script manager needs to be taken out back.

Comment: is it possible it has something to do with the partial page rendering of scriptmanager? So document.ready() isn't getting triggered?

Comment: @Programmer - taken out back?

Comment: @JohnOhara Scriptmanager is microsofts version of managing scripts, whereas there are often better solutions, like a bundler or cdn or grunt, gulp combination.Scriptmanager is most likely loading files you don't want, at the wrong time. Taken out back would mean, .Destroy.  Here is an article from 2007 that explains the qualms, https://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/scriptmanager-loadscriptsbeforeui-explained

Answer (score 1):

The first method populates variables as it executes:

```
var pub = {}, $ctl = $("#loan-selector"),
    $sliderAmount = $ctl.find(".slider-amount:first"),
    $widgetAmount = $sliderAmount.find(".widget:first");
```

So `#loan-selector`, `.slider-amount:first` and `.widget:first` need to be rendered in the page's DOM before this is called.

The second variant populates when `loanSelector.init()` is called, and by the place in your code where you call it the DOM is loaded.

`<asp:ScriptManager>` gives you a server side collection of scripts controls can add to easily, but it renders to a list of `<script>` tags and order can be important - another control in the page can mean that the DOM you're relying on hasn't loaded by the time your code runs. Scripts run in order but don't wait for the DOM render to finish.

jQuery has it's own component structure you can use instead, and a DOM ready method that you can rely on - you're already using it in `DefaultInit.js`, which is why the `loanSelector.init()` can access the DOM while the directly executed code does not.

You already have a fix, and your second script is *better practice* because it's not dependent on time of execution.

Another alternative would be to call your `loanSelector` function in the `$(document).ready`:

```
$(function(){
    // In this DOM ready function your elements should be ready to find
    var loanSelector = ...
    ...

    // And you may not need this, as you can init in the actual function
    loanSelector.init();
});
```